# No man page for strcpy_s

Tags: gcc, manpage

I don't have the man page for some c11 string functions such as `strcpy_s` and `strncpy_s`. I  have the most updated version of `gcc` but somehow it doesn't recognize `gcc -std=c11 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic` with `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` before `#include <string.h>`. I'd like to read the man pages to find out why.

I have already done `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install glibc-doc`. So far I also installed `manpages-dev`, `manpages-posix-dev`, Any idea? I also would like to know, if I want to install man page of X, how do I even know what to install? Is there a man page search function we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a set of manpages for the C standard. There is one for the POSIX standard, which overlaps significantly with the C standard but isn't the same. And while there's one for the system C library, which would be glibc, [glibc doesn't implement these functions either](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#Why_no_strlcpy_.2F_strlcat.3F), so you won't find them in the glibc documentation.

There is https://manpages.ubuntu.com/ where you can search Ubuntu manpages online. Each manpage will also show which package it is from.

Comment: Thanks, gotcha, searched ubuntu manpages and didn't find it. Guess it was not implemented in gcc after all.